# Can Apache Cordova generate certificates?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, x509, pki

Can Cordova be used to:

1. Generate a key pair.
2. Generate a certificate signing request (CSR).
3. Import a signed certificate?

Ideally I'd like this to work on both iOS and Android. I want to be able to generate a certificate, get it signed and install it into the system keystore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Cordova will not generate the key pair or certificates. You will have to login to apple developer portal and generate the certificate, provisional and extract .p12

Check this for ios certificate generation steps https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203808748-iOS-Creating-a-Distribution-Certificate-and-p12-File

Comment: ok, i didn't think so.  this is not a certificate thats used by the app, rather by the user.